# Netbeans Resolve missing server

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I've encountered a problem with my Netbeans 6.1 IDE.

After an unsuccessful update, Netbeans stopped recognizing Apache and Glassfish servers and requested me to resolve a missing server error, after which I opened a window to add a server, except there were none listed. Trying to add servers in the list yields no results as there isn't even a single server type to be chosen.

Reinstalling Netbeans didn't fix the problem. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstaling i didn`t done that, and the result was the same. More people had complains about this but i found no direct answer. I have done it the "hard" way and downloaded 6.5 version and everything is ok after instalation.

Comment: I'm still having this issue on netbean 6.9. Very frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstalled did you manually delete the "C:\Documents and Settings\omuhammed.netbeans" directory? apart from deleting the folder in "Program Files"? before reinstalling? This usually works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened with me also. As I opened one project which was created by some other user. But here it says, server is missing and I need to resolve it. When select Resolve server missing problem, window with blank list of servers is shown. When I opened 'Server Manager' window, there it is showing Bundled Tomcat. but there is noway to add the same server to the required project. At the same time, some projects, created in the same machine is running properly.

I could not see any proper reason and solution for the problem even in the net resources also.

any and all suggestion are highly appreciated.

Sajan

Comment: I searched on the net and conclusion is that the bug is fixed with new versions of Netbeans, so i "solve" the problem by downloading and installing new version and that is only suggestion i can give to you.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalled the netbeans, then i delete the "C:\Documents and Settings.netbeans", "C:\Documents and Settings.nbi", "C:\Documents and Settings.netbeans-derby", and "C:\Documents and Settings.netbeans-registration" directories. After that i reinstall the netbeans. It works! Thank you omer mohammed!

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project and next click *resolve missing server*. Open dialog box so you will add server in current glash fish server next solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While installing select customize button. Select only tomcat, un-check glass fish and then proceed installation. It will work like charm.